# Checking if headers include what they use

Tags: c++, dependencies, include, header-files, include-what-you-use

Are there tools that will parse a C++  project and decide
whether the header files include what they use:
i.e. if a  file Foo.cc (or Foo.h) mentions some class  Bar (e.g. vector) then
it itself includes a header file
defining the class (a file defining Bar e.g. `<vector>`) ?

Edit: I want to clarify: if a header file Foo.h mentions vector and one of its includes
already included vector, the compiler is happy. I don't want that. If Foo.h mentions vector
at all, it should include it directly and not depend on another header. Does the compiler catch this?

Comment: Could you make the question a bit clearer? But, as for now, it looks like the only thing you need is to run the compiler on your files...

Comment: There are static analysis tools like PC-Lint that report missing header includes. Do you want something like that or a tool that automatically imports all missing headers?

Comment: A simple way is to randomly permute `#include` directives, and see if it compiles (automate it !). Otherwise, without compiler support (which I doubt exist), it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler will do this for you.  A number of C++ style guides strongly recommend that for this reason all .cpp files should include the corresponding header as the first substantive include directive.

Comment: Then the trick is checking the header files that don't have a corresponding source file.

Comment: You can pass a header file to the compiler exactly the same way as a cpp file.  It's easier though just to make every header have a cpp file even if it's empty apart from the include.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: It costs nothing (1) to just create an empty source file for this purpose. (1) apart from a bit of build time I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a script for this. here's a simplified version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# hcheck: Check header file syntax (works on source files, too...)
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"
    exit 1
fi

for f in "$@" ; do
    case $f in
        *.c | *.cpp | *.cc | *.h | *.hh | *.hpp )
            echo "#include \"$f\"" > hcheck.cpp
            printf "\n\033[4mChecking $f\033[0m\n"
            make -s hcheck.o
            rm -f hcheck.o hcheck.cpp
            ;;
    esac
done
```

You need to have a `Makefile`, of course. If you don't want that, then replace the `make` line with an appropriate `gcc` command (don't forget any flags!). You'll also need to tweak it if your `Makefile` puts objects somewhere other than the current directory.

I'm sure there are plenty of improvements to be made. When I tell people about this, the knee-jerk response is "Compiling headers is a stupid idea," but it's worked well for me and can be used on headers that don't have sources or aren't included first in the source.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what the script does?

Comment: My script takes the argument list from the command line, and for each one that is a C or C++ file of some form, it creates a one-line `.cpp` file that `#include`s the file being tested and then tells `make` to create an object from that source file. `make` generally has a generic suffix rule to create any `.o` from any `.cpp` in one step, so this rule gets called (along with any variable settings by the makefile). If your file is good, nothing is printed except "Checking" and the filename. If your file is bad, then the compiler errors are printed after the "Checking" line.

Answer (score 0):

One way to ease the burden of reaching the goal of self sufficient headers is to make sure that whatever class (usually) or free functions (sometimes) are declared there have very specific intentions, as in adhering to the single responsibility principle. By doing that, there will be fewer dependencies that require headers to be included.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a tool. The problem isn't as easy to solve as it would seem. For example, which header files should the following include in order to be self-sufficient?

```
#ifdef FOO
  std::vector<int> getVector();
#endif

  void doStuff(std::string);
```

It might, might not, need to include `<vector>`. That depends on whether `FOO` is defined, and that might or might not be defined, *depending on what was included before this file*.

In general, preprocessor macros can really mess with any attempt at reading a header "in isolation".

Comment: Which is why my answer uses `make`, which should have all the necessary flags defined for the build. But that brings in its own assumptions. Also, in your example, the `#include <vector>` line would be put inside a `#ifdef FOO`/`#endif` pair.

Comment: but what if the define doesn't come from the compiler? What if it depends on a `#define` in another header, which may or may not be included before this one? And sure, the `#include` should be put inside the `#ifdef`/`#endif` pair. But automatically *verifying* that this is done correctly just got quite a lot harder

Comment: A header expecting a symbol to be defined on entry should invoke `#error` if that symbol is not defined. Or it should set a default. This is a valid test. Further, one could invoke `export DEFINES=-DMODE_TWO` or whatever on their command line so `make` picks up the variable. Again, if your requirements are complex, then you need to script the tests.